undefined method `images' for nil rails active_storage
_pin.html
'''
<% @pin.images.each do |image| %>

 <div id="<%= dom_id pin %>">

  <div class="carousel-cell">
<div class="panel.panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading.pin_image">
      <p>
          <%= image_tag (pin.image.variant(resize_to_limit: [500, 500]))  %>
          
 </p>
 </div>
 
 <div class="panel-body">
 </div>
 <div class="panel-footer">
 </div>
 
  </div>
        
</div>
</div>
 <% end %>

'''
index.html
'''
<div id="pins">

<div class="carousel" data-flickity='{ "cellAlign": "left", "contain": true }'>

  <% @pins.each do |pin| %>
    <%= render pin %>
    <p>
      <%= link_to "Show this pin", pin %>
    </p>
  <% end %>

'''
pin.rb
'''
class Pin < ApplicationRecord
has_many_attached :images
end

'''
form
'''
 <%= form_with(model: pin) do |form| %>
      <% if pin.errors.any? %>
        <div style="color: red">
          <h2><%= pluralize(pin.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this pin from being saved:</h2>
    
          <ul>
            <% pin.errors.each do |error| %>
              <li><%= error.full_message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    
      <div>
        <%= form.label :title, style: "display: block" %>
        <%= form.text_field :title %>
      </div>
    
      <div>
        <%= form.label :description, style: "display: block" %>
        <%= form.textarea :description %>
      </div>
    
    <div>
    <%= form.file_field :photos, :multiple => true %></br>
    </div>
    
      <div>
        <%= form.submit %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

'''
keep getting stuck with image uploads can someone help me fix quick? trying to set up some js and a pins kinda thing. fought for 2 days to get this for can i get a quick hand?
will poost further questions here. ..............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
edit
pins controller
'''
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pin, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /pins or /pins.json
  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end

  # GET /pins/1 or /pins/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /pins/new
  def new
    @pin = Pin.new
  end

  # GET /pins/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /pins or /pins.json
  def create
    @pin = Pin.new(pin_params)
        images.each do |image|
          @pin.images.attach(image)
          end
    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.save
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: "Pin was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @pin }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /pins/1 or /pins/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @pin.update(pin_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @pin, notice: "Pin was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @pin }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @pin.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /pins/1 or /pins/1.json
  def destroy
    @pin.destroy!

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to pins_path, status: :see_other, notice: "Pin was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params.expect(:id))
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def pin_params
     
      params.require(:pin).permit( :images => [])
    end
end

'''

@pin is nil, probably in your pin.html -- you just dumped a bunch of html in the question

noob sorry just tired of getting stuck at this girhub ai thing would be cool

Do not put a space between the method name and the parens in Ruby. What image_tag (...) is actually doing is image_tag((...)) so if you add more than one argument it will cause a syntax error.

In "_pin.html.erb" you need to change this:
@pin.images.each do |image|

to
pin.images.each

@pin is an unassigned instance variable (which will cause this call to be nil.images resulting in the error you are reporting). pin on the other hand is the implicit local variable set when you call render pin (assuming that pin is a Pin object).
Additionally render can accept an entire collection so you could clean this up a bit more using:
index.html.erb
<div id="pins">
    <div class="carousel" data-flickity='{ "cellAlign": "left", "contain": true }'>
        <%= render @pins %>
    </div>
</div>

_pin.html.erb
<% pin.images.each do |image| %>
    <div id="<%= dom_id pin %>">
        <div class="carousel-cell">
            <div class="panel.panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading.pin_image">
                  <p><%= image_tag(pin.image.variant(resize_to_limit: [500, 500])) %></p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body"></div>
                <div class="panel-footer"></div>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
<% end %>
<p><%= link_to "Show this pin", pin %></p>

Your form has issues too, which are technically outside the scope of this question but:
 <%= form.file_field :photos, :multiple => true %></br>

I assume this is supposed to be the "images" but I cannot say for sure and your pin_params in the controller do not whitelist :title or :description coming from the form.
